# Get img size inside a list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm having problems getting an image size inside a list, using jQuery.
I'm having no problem to get the li element sizes, but every time I try with the image, it returns 0. What should I do?

```
<ul class="company-list">
    <li>
        <img src="<?php echo APP_URL; ?>images/partnership/img_01.jpg" alt="" >                         
    </li> 
</ul>


$( "ul.company-list li img" ).each(function( index ) {
        var imgHeight = $(this).height();
        var imgWidth = $(this).width();

        var imProp = imgWidth / imgHeight;
      console.log(imgHeight);
    });
```

Comment: maybe this link can be a reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this [demo : [https://jsfiddle.net/kn74f95a/2/]](https://jsfiddle.net/kn74f95a/2/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $( "ul.company-list li" ).each(function() {
    let image = $(this).find('img').on('load', function(){
        let imgHeight = this.naturalHeight;
        let imgWidth = this.naturalWidth;

      let imProp = imgWidth / imgHeight;
      console.log(imgWidth, imgHeight);
    });    
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="company-list">
    <li>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/480/320" alt="" >                         
    </li> 
    <li>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/480/360" alt="" >                         
    </li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

That happened because you are trying get width and height of image before **loading**. You must be sure first the picture is loaded and then get the width and height:

look at this snippet to understand. First the `imgHeight` is zero but after click button (I am sure the picture loaded) `imgHeight` has value:

```js
showWidth();
 function showWidth() {
     $("ul.company-list li img").each(function (index) {
         var imgHeight = $(this).height();
         var imgWidth = $(this).width();

         var imProp = imgWidth / imgHeight;
         console.log(imgHeight);
     });
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="showWidth()">click to show width</button>
    <ul class="company-list">
        <li>
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpy7M.jpg?s=420&g=1" alt="">
        </li>
</ul>
```

So you can use `load` event to make sure after loading the picture, you get the `imgHeight`:

```js
$("ul.company-list li img").each(function (index) {
    $(this).on('load', function () {
        var imgHeight = $(this).height();
        var imgWidth = $(this).width();
        var imProp = imgWidth / imgHeight;
        console.log(imgHeight);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<ul class="company-list">
    <li>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpy7M.jpg?s=420&g=1" alt="">
    </li>
</ul>
```